# how to make group of views can be scrolled vertically along with tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, tableview

I am sorry, I am new in iOS, I need to set group of views (`ImageView` and `labels`) above `TableView` like the image below, but I need to make that group of views can be scrolled vertically.

in Android, I can simply use `coordinator layout`. I have no idea how to make something like this in iOS using UIKit ?

[image]

Comment: that orange view is not moving/scrolling. just add as a subview to view controller and center veriically and pin right

Comment: @Scriptable sorry for the confusion. I mean.... the group views are that views above the table view, there is circular an image view, a segmented control and some labels there

Comment: @Alexa289 - try to provide a little more detail to explain what you are trying to do. Do you mean you want the "top section" - with round-image, labels and segmented control to remain visible, that is, to ***NOT*** scroll? While the rows scroll up and down below it?

Comment: @DonMag no, I want to make that top section can be scrolled vertically along with the rows of my table view. like the .gif image above

Comment: @Alexa289 - ok, I thought the image you showed is what you already **have** and you wanted different behavior. In this case, the answer given is correct... either make that "top view" the first row in your table, or make it the table header view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is that you can set the above views as the first cell or section header in table view.